# How can I set the storage engine to wiredTiger with the 2.4 config syntax?

Tags: mongodb, upgrade

I'm currently upgrading my mongodb from 2.4 to 3.x
One of the steps is to change the storage engine to wiredTiger.
Can I still use the 2.4 syntax in my mongod.conf file or do I need to change everything over to yaml?

I've tried using

`storage.engine = "wiredTiger"`
and
`storageEngine = "wiredTiger"`

But neither worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I was not able to get it to work and instead upgraded my config file to YAML.

However supposedly it works if you remove the quotes around wiredTiger so you end up with `storageEngine=wiredTiger`